# sqlite3 not found in virtualenv

Tags: django, sqlite

I've just installed python and Django in a vitual env.  All seems to work except when I type python manage.py dbshell when I get:

CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.

I thought that Django would install sqlite3 by default.

In settings.py I have this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578231/error-while-accessing-sqlite3-shell-from-django-application

Answer (score 1):

Run 
    `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`
and then try to sync your database again. If your path does not contain your specified database file django will automatically create one however, sqlite3 does not come prepackaged with django as far as I am aware of.